# produce boolean matrix from another matrix in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have matrix T(60000*1). in each row of this matrix I have one number from 0 to 9.

I want to make another matrix Y(60000*10) from T matrix. Y is a boolean matrix.if matrix T in row 2 have value of 3 then matrix row 2 of matrix Y must be like

[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

this is my code 
Mnist is my dataset

```
T=MnistTrainY;
Z = ones(length(T), 1) * [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
Y = (Z == T);
```

this is works really fine but I want to know is there any way which is more efficient with better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `bsxfun` to create your desired `logical` matrix. This will perform element-wise checks for equality ([`eq`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html)) between all combinations of elements in `T` and the array `0:9`.

```
Y = bsxfun(@eq, T, 0:9);
```

If you're on MATLAB version R2016b or later, you can remove `bsxfun` since it will perform the dimension broadcasting automatically.

```
Y = T == 0:9;
```

Comment: @mkafiyan It is a function handle to `eq` which is the same as `==`

Comment: aha yes I use R2016b version of matlab so I can use `Y = T == 0:9;` . thank you :D